# Facebook follow button remove after follow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

Since there is no events from facebook api on follow button is there any way to make the button disappear when someone actually clicks follow.

For like the event was edge.create:

```
   (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7&appId";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
                        function (response) {
                            $(".fb-like").remove();
```

Unfortunately for fb-follow there is nothing.

So is there any possible way to make it work with javascript/jquery.
I've tried something like this but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="fb-follow" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/" data-layout="button" data-size="large" data-show-faces="true" z-index:"555" id="fb1"></div>


    <script>$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fb-follow').click(function(e){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});</script>
```

Comment: Actually, the code you provided works. You can try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/27w11b6h/

Comment: It works when it's some text or a normal button, on jsfiddle the sdk for fb is missing. So the "follow button" doesn't load there.

Comment: No, there is not. And Facebook does not even want you to do this for the Like button - you are not allowed to change _anything_ based on whether the user liked your page or not. Plus, giving the user the possibility to remove their like again in the same place where they originally liked the item, is just a matter of good manners ;-)

Comment: How can you say that doesnt even want? They actually gave a way to know whether the user liked it or not. I'm not changing anything. Thanks for the moral, but that's not something I'm asking for when I come to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting error in this code.

**js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7&appId";**

(test.html:25 GET file://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)

It should be :

**js.src ="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7&appId";**

Comment: I am not running it on local, so when it's on live web server, it doesnt give an error like this.